# Aspx to Razor Select List MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, select, razor

I have converted my MVC3 application to MVC5, I had to change all views to razor.  Having a challenge with a select list:
In ASPX view that works I am using the following:

```
<select id="Profession" name="Profession" style="width: 235px; background-color: #FFFFCC;">
<% List<string> allProfessions = ViewBag.AllProfessions;
string selectedProfession;
if (Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Profession))
    selectedProfession = Model.Profession;
    else
    selectedProfession = allProfessions[0];
foreach (var aProfession in allProfessions)
{
string selectedTextMark = aProfession == selectedProfession ? " selected=\"selected\"" : String.Empty;
Response.Write(string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\" {1}>{2}</option>", aProfession, selectedTextMark, aProfession));
}%>
</select>
```

In Razor I am using:

```
 <select id="Profession" name="Profession" style="width: 235px; background-color: #FFFFCC;">
      @{List<string> allProfessions = ViewBag.AllProfessions;
        string selectedProfession;}
      @{if (Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Profession))
        {selectedProfession = Model.Profession;}
        else {selectedProfession = allProfessions[0];}
       }
       @foreach (var aProfession in allProfessions)
       {
        string selectedTextMark = aProfession == selectedProfession ?  
        "selected=\"selected\"" : String.Empty;
        Response.Write(string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\" {1}>{2}</option>", 
        aProfession, selectedTextMark, aProfession));
        }
   </select>
```

The list shows up at the top of the page, I can't figure out where is the problem.  Would appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's happening because of the `Response.Write`. Try this:

```
 @Html.Raw(string.Format("<option value=\"{0}\" {1}>{2}</option>", aProfession,
           selectedTextMark, aProfession))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create your dropdown manually like that. Just use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Profession, ViewBag.AllProfessions, new { style = "..." })
```

**UPDATE**

> I tried your solution but got this error: Extension method cannot by dynamically dispatched

And, that's why I despise `ViewBag`. I apologize, as my answer was a little generic. `Html.DropDownList` requires the list of options parameter to be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Since `ViewBag` is a dynamic, the types of its members cannot be ascertained, so you must cast explicitly:

```
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.AllProfessions
```

However, your `AllProfessions` is a simple array, so that cast won't work when the value gets inserted at run-time, but that can be easily fixed by casting it to a `List<string>` and then converting the items with a `Select`:

```
((List<string>)ViewBag.AllProfessions).Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m, Text = m })
```

There again, you see why dynamics are not that great, as that syntax is rather awful. The way you should be handling this type of stuff is to use your model or, preferably, view model to do what it should do: hold domain logic. Add a property to hold your list of profession choices:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProfessionChoices { get; set; }
```

And then, in your controller action, populate this list before rendering the view:

```
var model = new YourViewModel();
...
model.ProfessionChoices = repository.GetAllProfessions().Select(m => new SelectListItem { Value = m.Name, Text = m.Name });
return View(model);
```

`repository.GetAllProfessions()` is shorthand for whatever you're using as the source of your list of professions, and the `Name` property is shorthand for how you get at the text value of the profession: you'll need to change that appropriately to match your scenario.

Then in your view, you just need to do:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Profession, Model.ProfessionChoices)
```

Given that you don't have this infrastructure already set up, it may seem like a lot to do just for a drop down list, and that's a reasonable thing to think. However, working in this way will keep your view lean, make maintenance tons easier, and best of all, keep everything strongly-typed so that if there's an issue, you find out at compile-time instead of run-time.

Comment: I tried your solution but got this error:
Extension method cannot by dynamically dispatched.

Comment: Thank you so much Chris for taking the time to assist.